# when i click on popup button it tack load and i don't want it

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

when the popup window appears , I enter one value and click on the button.
problem here is that when i click on the button it will load the page and inserted value will get cleared.
So, I want to do that when I click on the button, it should not trigger page load instead, my button click event should fire.

here's one image 
    [image]

my main question is when I click on the button it will load page and I want that to be stopped and my button click event to fire.

button code:
`<asp:Button ID="btnfirstnext" TabIndex="1" runat="server" Text="Next" class="next1 action-button" OnClick="btnfirstnext_Click" />`

javascript code 
`$(".next1").click(function () {
                if (animating) return true;
                animating = true;

```
            current_fs = $(this).parent();
            next_fs = $(this).parent().next();

            //activate next step on progressbar using the index of next_fs
            $("#progressbar li").eq($("fieldset").index(next_fs)).addClass("active");

            //show the next fieldset
            next_fs.show();

            //hide the current fieldset with style
            current_fs.animate({ opacity: 0 }, {
                step: function (now, mx) {
                    //as the opacity of current_fs reduces to 0 - stored in "now"
                    //1. scale current_fs down to 80%
                    scale = 1 - (1 - now) * 0.2;
                    //2. bring next_fs from the right(50%)
                    left = (now * 50) + "%";
                    //3. increase opacity of next_fs to 1 as it moves in
                    opacity = 1 - now;
                    current_fs.css({ 'transform': 'scale(' + scale + ')' });
                    next_fs.css({ 'left': left, 'opacity': opacity });
                },
                duration: 800,
                complete: function () {
                    current_fs.hide();
                    animating = false;
                },
                //this comes from the custom easing plugin
                easing: 'easeInOutBack'
              // $('btnfirstnext').trigger('click');

            });
        });`
```

Button Click Code:
`protected void btnfirstnext_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           lbltry.text="hello this code is not work if i use onclientclick=false";
        }`

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show the *relevant* code.

Comment: It is hard to understand what you are asking. Could you please reformat your question?

Comment: why you used class as identifier? use Id and return false when easing is done.

Comment: i use class becouse of popup

Answer (score 0):

I think you shouldn't use the asp.net control `<asp:Button />`, because when the `OnClick`  event fired, the whole page will send back to server to invoke the event handler you register in the backend C# Code, the `btnfirstnext_Click` method, so if you want stop reloading page, you can replace the `asp:Button` control with `<a/>` or other html tags, and write the click callback function in js code, maybe like this:

```
<!-- html -->
<a id="btnfirstnext" class="next1 action-button">Next</a>

// javascript code
$('#btnfirstnext').click(function(){
    // your logic here
});
```

By the way, if you think javascript code cann't handle your business needs, you can make a ajax request in the click callback function to invoke the method of backend

Hope this can help!